# Taking different Form inputs foreach iteration of the for loop in Django View function

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I want to take start_channel and end_channel input from user in Django function view to visualization purposes. I have different data to visualize. In my view function, I need to take start_channel and end_channel input for each data.

This is my code:

```
def visualize_power_prob(request, test_set_pk): # this is my django function view.
   ...  # some operations here
   for data_idx, data_doc in enumerate(data_set):
       # I need to take start_channel and end_channel input here via using form.
       # And then I'll use these informations to visualize the current data
```

How can I take user input for each data without breaking the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Django formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/) for getting the same input multiple times. Example:

```
# forms.py
from django import forms


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    start_channel = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    end_channel = forms.CharField(max_length=50)



# views.py
from django.forms import formset_factory

from .forms import MyForm


def visualize_power_prob(request, test_set_pk):  # this is my django function view.
    ...  # some operations here
    MyFormSet = formset_factory(MyForm, max_num=len(data_set), min_num=len(data_set))
    formset = MyFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for data_idx, data_doc in enumerate(data_set):
            # I need to take start_channel and end_channel input here via using form.
            # And then I'll use these informations to visualize the current data
            form_data = formset.cleaned_data[data_idx]
            # now form_data contains 'start_channel' and 'end_channel' data
            # use it as you want
```

Assuming that `data_set` is `list` you can calculate number of forms to be submitted by `len(data_set)` and get that number of input data from the user.